# URLs are encoded in google index

Tags: encoding, indexing

Google is indexing pages like below, I think it is an encoding problem but i do not know what might be causing it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
http://www.medikalyasam.com/index.php?do%252525252525253Dcatalog%252525252525252FnewProducts%252525253D%2525252526type%252525253Dlist%3D%26type%3Dlist=&type=catalog=&type=catalog
```